# well-known-type android nfc intent-filter

Tags: java, android, nfc, intentfilter, ndef

I want to filter the following Type:

urn:nfc:wkt:Hs

in the android manifest.

I write the data as follows:

```
public NdefRecord createHandoverSelectRecord(byte[] payload) {
    NdefRecord record = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN,
    NdefRecord.RTD_HANDOVER_SELECT, new byte[0], payload);
    return record;
}
```

How can I filter now correctly the Type?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot filter for these messages. Presumably (hopefully?), because Android will at some point be extended with the functionality to handle Handover messages itself?
See [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#filtering-intents) for what types you can filter for.